# Private members in pimpl class?

Tags: c++, pimpl-idiom

Is there any reason for the implementation class as used in the pimpl idiom to have any private members at all? The only reason I can really think of is to protect yourself from yourself -- i.e. the private members serve to enforce some kind of contract between the class and the user, and in this case the class and the user are rather intimately related, so it seems unnecessary.

Comment: Assuming a pooled implementation for read-only strings, the implementation class can very well have reference counting so as it knows when to free the memory, if required.

Comment: dirkgently: I would imagine that, in order to have a single count for all references to a string, that count would have to be stored centrally, within the string and not the wrapper.  What am I missing here?

Comment: @Steven Sudit: Because it would violate the design -- the reference count is strictly speaking not part of the data structure required to represent the string.

Comment: @Dirk: The reference-counted string in Plauger's STL violates design, then, since the count is stored alongside the characters.  While another layer could be added, wouldn't that mean that a counted string points to a shared counter struct that itself points to a raw string?  This would only be safe so long as the counter struct never shares strings with other struct instances.

Comment: @Steven Sudit: Another layer? Not sure what you mean. Anyway, I haven't seen that code and I guess there must be a good reason to implement it that way -- so any comment would be irrelevant. At any rate, the standard library does revert to a few tricks at times to improve efficiency.

Comment: @Dirk: I don't want to belabor this, but I do want to be clear.  Consider a reference counted string class, called RefString, holding a shared reference to an instance of String.  It also has to hold a reference to a count, which will be shared whenever the String reference is.  There are basically three ways to do this.  First, the count could be a dynamically-allocated integer all by itself.  Second, the RefString could point to a String that contains a count built in.  Third, the RefString could point to an intermediate struct that contains the count and a reference to the string.  Clearer?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think people are confusing the Pimpl **idiom** with Adapter/Bridge/Strategy **patterns**. Idioms are specific to a language. Patterns can apply to many languages.

The Pimpl idiom was devised to address the following problem in C++: Private members of a class are visible in the class declaration, which adds unnecessary #include dependencies to the user of the class. This idiom is also known as *compiler firewall*.

If the implementation is written directly in the outer class's corresponding *.cpp file, and is not accessible outside the module, then **I think its perfectly fine to simply use a struct for the Pimpl class**. To further re-enforce the idea that implementations are not meant to be directly re-used, I define them as a private inner struct:

```
// foo.h
class Foo : boost::noncopyable
{
public:
   ...

private:
   struct Impl;
   boost::scoped_ptr<Impl> impl_;
};

// foo.cpp
struct Foo::Impl
{
   // Impl method and member definitions
};

// Foo method definitions
```

As soon as there's a header file for the implementation class, I think we are no longer talking about the Pimpl idiom. We are rather talking about Adapter, Bridge, Strategy, interface classes, etc...

Just my 2 cents.

Answer (score 6):

Depends on your implementation of pImpl - specifically where you enforce the class invariant, but in general I see no need for the impl part to have protected/private members. In fact, I usually declare it as a struct.

Answer (score 4):

In theory a pimpl class is still just a class like any other.  That it is a concrete implementation of an interface doesn't mean that other code isn't a client of the pimpl class itself.

That said, in practice I have found that pimpl classes tend to be much closer to structs with some member functions rather than full fledged objects, and have less need to separate the interface from the implementation.

Answer (score 2):

Why shouldn't it have private members?  Just because you're defining one interface as PIMPL doesn't mean that you will at no other time want to use the class.

It's still a class.  Data should probably be private or protected.  Operations on data that will never be accessible to the public, private or protected.  Operations that you might wish to expose, protected, or public.

Comment: My main reason for not wanting private members is sheer laziness -- I don't want to provide accessors. I realize there may also be members that should be private and don't require accessors as well.

Comment: It is really a "private" class - accessible only within one cpp file. A C-style struct is just fine for the purpose in most cases.

Comment: Nemanja: This assumes the outside and inside are written at the same time.  I've added pimpl after the fact to existing implementations.

Comment: @Steven. Not sure I understand your point. If you change your existing class to use pImpl, you keep the interface of the original class as-is, and move all the private data to a struct that is visible only within the implementation cpp file, right?

Comment: @xzqx: Why do you need to write so many accessors?  Is all your data actually accessible for public use?  Why aren't operations internal to the class?

Comment: @Nemanja: The use case I'm talking about is when the impl class already exists and isn't even under your control, so you write the pimpl class to hide the impl away.  The public interface of the pimpl class will be *similar to* that of the impl, but it may well be a subset or otherwise hide some aspects.

Comment: @Steven: Wouldn't your use case be the Adapter or Bridge pattern, rather than Pimpl?

Comment: @Emile: Exactly what I thought.

Comment: Based on http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill05.htm, I think what I'm describing qualifies as pimpl.

Comment: Perhaps there is a gray area between "pure" Pimpl and the Adapter/Bridge patterns?

Comment: @Emile: Perhaps.  Or maybe they're somewhat orthogonal, with pimpl being a language-specific technique that can be used to implement the more general Adapter/Bridge pattern (but also to implement other patterns).

Answer (score 1):

> The only reason I can really think of
>   is to protect yourself from yourself

Which is why "private" and "protected" are there in the first place. Of course you should use them in your implementation - the only time I would not is if the implementation has no behaviour (in which case it isn't really an implementation).

Answer (score 0):

(I misunderstood the question, so I'm changing my answer.)

The implementing class, which is pointed to by the class with the pimpl, should be a regular class, with just as much reason to hide private details as any other.  In fact, it's often a pre-existing class, with the pimpl layer added later to break dependencies and perhaps simplify the interface a bit.

Comment: The pre-existing class is the "outer" one, not the "impl" part.

Comment: I've seen it go both ways.  Sometimes pimpl is a way to put a consistent interface over implementations that are subject to change.  Other times, pimpl is a way to to hide away the implementation completely, breaking compile-time dependencies.  In fact, both can be goals.

Answer (score 0):

Because `private` means better data encapsulation.

It seems silly, I know, but we have a way of defining interfaces at work that is very simple:

```
class Interface;

class Concrete { public: .... private: Interface* m_interface; }

class ConcreteFoo: public Interface {};
```

The main advantage: you can swap for another `ConcreteBar` at any moment. It is, in fact, a combination of `Pimpl` and `Strategy` pattern, and the constructor of `Concrete` will call a `Factory` that will be responsible to serve the effective object.

If you cannot think of a second way of implementing the heart, just encapsulate it in a class. This way if you later have to refactor, you'll just have to compose an abstract `Interface` with the exact same set of methods, change a few pointers (and the constructor) and you'll be all right ;)